# dredge in MuMin (R) keeps models with higher order terms without their respective lower order terms

Tags: r, mumin

I am using the function dredge from package MuMin for model selection. My model has a polynomial in it. I was under the impression (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/1.42.1/topics/dredge, see "Interactions") that MuMin as standard ditches models that include the higher order term without its respective lower order term; however when I use it the top model includes only the higher order term.

Here is the code I am using to make the global model, which includes `hour`: at both first and second order

```
sc.mod.env.hour<-clmm(seedcat~hour+I(hour^2)+MeanSpeed+RH+TKE+AirTemp+MeanUpdraft+(1|jdayfac), data=sc.data, na.action = na.fail, Hess =TRUE)
```

However when I run dredge:

```
dro.env.hour<-dredge(sc.mod.env.hour)
```

The output includes models that include `I(hour^2)` without `hour`

```
Model selection table 
    (Intrc)   ArTmp    hour hour^2 MnSpd    MnUpd     RH      TKE df   logLik   AICc  delta weight
46        + -1.2170         -3.340 1.894          -4.219          13 -571.772 1170.5   0.00  0.154
62        + -1.3410         -3.478 1.964  0.30990 -4.269          14 -570.882 1170.9   0.37  0.128
45        +                 -2.882 2.052          -3.214          12 -573.245 1171.3   0.81  0.103
47        +         -0.3595 -2.670 1.942          -3.601          13 -572.374 1171.7   1.20  0.084
63        +         -0.4495 -2.712 2.010  0.33870 -3.645          14 -571.350 1171.8   1.30  0.080
```

I have tried also using `poly(hour,2)` to define the global model but this results in only including a single term for hour.

I am using `clmm` but have tried a simpler model using `lm` and got the same result.

Any guidance appreciated thankyou. I wasn't sure if this should be on crossvalidated but it is a programming issue rather than a stats issue so thought it should be here.

EDIT: I have solved the issue by using subset:

```
dro.env.hour<-dredge(sc.mod.env.hour, subset=(dc(hour, I(hour^2)))
```

Although it is not clear why this is an issue in the first place.

Comment: Shouldn't this complaint be sent to the maintainer? It's not really a problem in coding but rather in what is legitimate statistically (not on-topic in SO).

Comment: `hour^2` can be seen as a higher-order term, but it is simply a transformed variable. There is no good reason `dredge` should keep it together with a "first-order" variable by default.

Comment: I didn't really intend it as a complaint, more that I thought I might have done something incorrectly, such as defining my terms wrong - if there is no good reason that dredge recognises hour^2 as a higher order term then presumably there is a way of defining the higher order term that dredge recognises, otherwise it would not be a thing that is assumed as default.

I assumed it was a mistake on my part as I haven't seen this reported as a problem elsewhere. I found a hack around it but that doesn't mean that my original method was correct.

Comment: the reason i considered it a coding issue rather than a stats issue is because the documentation states this:

_By default, marginality constraints are respected, so “all possible combinations” include only those containing interactions with their respective main effects and all lower order terms._ but maybe I am misinterpreting

Comment: @agorapotatoes: *interactions*

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has this question, I found this solution in MuMin manual:

Make a subset with a name first, in this case I want quadratic effects of X and Y)

```
msubset <- expression(  dc(X, `I(X^2)`) &
                        dc(`Y`, `I(Y^2)`))
```

Then the model, for example

```
mglm <- glm(response~X + I(X^2) + Y + I(Y^2)+ Z,
                  family=binomial,
                  na.action = "na.fail",
                  data=mdata)
```

Now dredge using the subset you specified

```
mmodels<-dredge(mglm, subset=msubset)
```

Check summary table

```
model.sel(mmodels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (untested!) is to use `poly(hour, 2)` rather than `hour + I(hour^2)` in the model (or, if you really want 'raw' rather than orthogonal polynomials, `poly(hour, 2, raw=TRUE)`). This way R can recognize that `poly()` is meant to be a single term. (The problem with `hour + I(hour^2)` is that it would take some fancy parsing within the model-frame construction machinery to be able to tell that these terms are related ...)