# How to make the dredge (MuMin) output from a model with "poly(x, 2)*factor" show both polynomial terms?

Tags: r, mumin, poly

Model structure:
fixed = Y ~ poly(x, 2) * factor

The dredge output shows only:
[...] factor, poly(x,2) , factor:poly(x,2)

instead of:
[...] factor, poly(x,1) , poly(x,2) , factor:poly(x,1) , factor:poly(x,2)

It is unclear for me how to interpret this output, since i can not tell whether the evaluation is done for the models with/without both orders 1 and 2 of variable x or not, i.e. just the higher order.
Besides, how can i see the evaluation of the models with only the order 1 of x?

Here:
[dredge in MuMin (R) keeps models with higher order terms without their respective lower order terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252019/dredge-in-mumin-r-keeps-models-with-higher-order-terms-without-their-respectiv)
the OP asked something very similar, but in relation to the funtion "poly" he only satated the following, and no answer dealt with it:
"I have tried also using poly(hour,2) to define the global model but this results in only including a single term for hour."

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get the table of *coefficients* (the default output of `"model.selection"` shows model *terms* with coefficient values only when there is only one coefficient for a term).
The `coef` method does that.