# Subsetting with dredge function (MuMin)

Tags: r, subset, mumin

I'm trying to subset a series of models dredged from a global model that has both linear & non-linear terms. There are no interactions e.g.

```
Glblm <- Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + I(X3^2) + X4 + X5 + X6 + I(X6^2) + X7 + I(X7^2)
```

I want to specify that X3^2 should never appear without X3, but X3 could appear alone without X3^2 (and the same for X6 & X7).

I have tried the following as I understood from the documentation:

```
ssm <-dredge (Glblm, subset=(X3| !I(X3^2)) && (X6| !I(X6^2)) && (X7| !I(X7^2)))
```

I also tried making a subset first as I read `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252019/dredge-in-mumin-r-keeps-models-with-higher-order-terms-without-their-respectiv`
e.g.

```
hbfsubset <- expression(  dc(X3, `I(X3^2)`) &  dc(`X6`, `I(X6^2)`)&  dc(`X7`, `I(X7^2)`))

ssm <-dredge (Glblm, subset=hbfsubset)
```

neither has produced a subset of models, instead the full list of models is returned when inspecting 'ssm' using:

```
model.sel(ssm)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A reproducible example from you is needed to pinpoint the issue, specifying what type of model you are fitting.

In simple linear models (`lm`, those examples provided in `MuMIn` handbook), the name of fitted terms is exactly the same as what you typed in the global model, but this may not be the case in more complex models (e.g. `glmmTMB`).

Here is an example:

```
library(MuMIn)
library(glmmTMB)

# a simple linear model, using Cement data from MuMIn
m1 <- lm(y ~ X1 + I(X1^2) + X2 + I(X2^2), data = Cement, na.action = "na.fail")

# dredge without a subset
d1 <- dredge(m1)
# 16 models produced

# dredge with a subset
d1_sub <- dredge(m1, subset = dc(`X1`, `I(X1^2)`) & dc(`X2`, `I(X2^2)`))
# 9 models produced, works totally fine


# a glmmTMB linear model
m2 <- glmmTMB(y ~ X1 + I(X1^2) + X2 + I(X2^2), data = Cement, na.action = "na.fail")

# dredge without a subset
d2 <- dredge(m2)
# 16 models produced

# dredge with a subset
d2_sub <- dredge(m2, subset = dc(`X1`, `I(X1^2)`) & dc(`X2`, `I(X2^2)`))
# 16 models produced, subset didn't work and no warning or error produced

# this is because the term names of a glmmTMB object in dredge() is not the same as the typed global model anymore:
names(d2_sub) 
# [1] "cond((Int))"   "disp((Int))"   "cond(X1)"      "cond(I(X1^2))" "cond(X2)"      "cond(I(X2^2))" "df"            "logLik"        "AICc"         
# [10] "delta"         "weight"   
# e.g., now the X1 in the typed global model is actually called cond(X1)

# what will work for glmmTMB:
d2_sub <- dredge(m2, subset = dc(`cond(X1)`, `cond(I(X1^2))`) & dc(`cond(X2)`, `cond(I(X2^2))`))
# 9 models produced
```